# How can I continue checking validation after first regex passes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex in a javascript that is checked onclientclick.  The code I have below works properly if the first check is false, I have a message displayed and it stops before submitting as I would like it to.  However, if the first validation checks fine, I want it to check the next set of validations but it just skips the rest and submits.  Am I missing something here?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function checkall() {

    var isValid21 = false;
    var regex21 = /(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/;
    isValid21 = regex21.test(document.getElementById("TimeTest").value);
    document.getElementById("spnError21").style.display = !isValid21 ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("TimeTest")
    return isValid21;

     var isValid2 = false;
     var DDLOne = document.getElementById("DropDownA");
     if (DDLOne.value == "") {
     document.getElementById("spnError2").style.display = !isValid2 ? "block" : "none";
     document.getElementById("DropDownA")
         return false;
     }

 var submit = 0;
         if (++submit > 1) {
             alert('Give me a second.');
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclientclick="return checkall();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: What do you think "return" means?

Comment: Why not just make each validation step a different function and then call a `validate()` function that calls the other validation functions? Why make a convoluted function when you can create multiple functions for validation and clean up your code?

Comment: Consider familiarizing a bit with [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return): *"The `return` statement **ends function execution**..."*

Comment: `return` ends the function. Put it in an `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is returning immediately after the first check, which is why the second one is never checked. You'll need to change your code to return an aggregate of the two "checks" at the end of your function. Also, your `submit` variable is declared inside the scope function, which means it will always get initialized to 0. I think you need to declare that outside your function. In addition, what are those empty `document.getElementById("...")` calls for? They dont do anything. Finally, you are returning `true` at the very end of your function. You'll need to tweak your logic rules and return the aggregate of `isValid21` and `isValid2` at the end. You'll have to do the tweaking yourself, as we don't know the required business rules.With all that, I'm not sure that this logic is sound, but this should at least get you going in the right direction:

```
var submit = 0;
function checkall() {
    var isValid21 = false;
    var isValid2 = false;
    var regex21 = /(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/;
    isValid21 = regex21.test(document.getElementById("TimeTest").value);
    document.getElementById("spnError21").style.display = !isValid21 ? "block" : "none";
    var DDLOne = document.getElementById("DropDownA");
    if (DDLOne.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("spnError2").style.display = !isValid2 ? "block" : "none";
        isValid2 = false;
    }
    if (++submit > 1) {
        alert('Give me a second.');
        isValid2 = false;
    }
    //SOME OTHER LOGIC RULES THAT CHANGE isValid2 TO TRUE...

    //YOU WILL NEED TO DO SOME ADDITIONAL LOGIC TWEAKING BEFORE THIS LINE. AS IT STANDS NOW, THIS WILL ALWAYS RETURN FALSE.
    return isValid21 && isValid2;
}
```